# unable to run aws command line tools

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have installed the AWS Command line tools and have also set the Env Variables, but why I type mon-cmd I am getting this error, I am not able to figure it out,kindly help me.

```
/usr/local/aws/bin/mon-cmd: line 12: /home/ubuntu/usr/local/aws/bin/service: No such file or directory
/usr/local/aws/bin/mon-cmd: line 12: exec: /home/ubuntu/usr/local/aws/bin/service: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have a user called `ubuntu`?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /home/ubuntu/usr/local/aws/bin/service`?

Comment: @Khaled ls: cannot access /home/ubuntu/usr/local/aws/bin/service: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the mon-cmd is looking for the binaries path in /home/ubuntu instead of /.

Can you show how you set the EC2_HOME environmental variable?  You an run something like `env |grep EC2`.

I have mine set like:

```
export EC2_HOME=~/ec2
```

I suspect you have it set similarly, but you probably want it set to / (i.e., `export EC2_HOME=/`) or something similar.

You may need to add /usr/local/aws/bin to your PATH, additionally.

Comment: I have set the EC2 home path as /usr/local/aws by export EC2_PATH=/usr/local/aws

Answer (score -1):

It's not EC2_PATH. Do this:

```
$ export EC2_HOME=/usr/local/aws
$ export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
```

Then, with your private key and certificate:

```
$ export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=~/.ec2/pk-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem 
$ export EC2_CERT=~/.ec2/cert-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.pem
```

Change X and Y for your respectives.